# Why does a C.D.F need to be right-continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question

As you may know, if $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space and $X\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^k$ is a random variable, then the *cumulative distribution function* of $X$ is defined as 
$$F_X(a):=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega\,\colon X(\omega)\leq a\})=\mathbb{P}\Big(X^{-1}\Big(\prod_{i\in [k]}(-\infty,a_i]\Big)\Big),\,\text{ for each } a\in\mathbb{R}^k.$$

This function is always right-continuous. That is, for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$ we have $\lim_{a\downarrow x}F_X(a)=F_X(x)$.

My question is: Why is this property important? Is there any capital result in probability theory that depends on it?

Comment: In an alternative history, c.d.f.'s might have been defined as $F_X(a)=\mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)<a\})$ with strict inequality, and then these functions would be continuous from the left rather than from the right. As far as I can see, the choice between the standard definition and this alternative one is purely a matter of convention.

Comment: Possibly interesting discussion: [Why aren't CDFs left-continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807120/why-arent-cdfs-left-continuous)

Comment: Both the standard convention and @AndreasBlass's alternative history continuous-on-the-left convention suffer from this defect: if $Y=-X$, the cdf $F_X(x)$ is not simply $1-F_Y(-x)$.  Some older authors (G.H. Hardy and D.V.Widder, eg) adopt a different convention: at jump discontinuities, $F(x)=(F(x-)+F(x+))/2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in a finite measure (by which I mean a finite $\sigma$-additive measure) space, if $\{A_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of measurable sets such that $A_i\supseteq A_{i+1}$ for all $i$, then $\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_i\right)=\inf_{n\in\Bbb N} \mu(A_i)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_i)$. In your special case where all the $A_i$-s are hyperrectangle in the form $R\left(a^{(i)}\right)=\left(-\infty,a^{(i)}_1\right]\times\cdots\times\left(-\infty, a^{(i)}_k\right]$ and $\mu=\Bbb P_X$, this translates to $$\mathbb P_X\left(R(a)\right)=\mathbb P_X\left(\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N} R\left(a^{(i)}\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P_X\left(R\left(a^{(i)}\right)\right)$$ for all $a^{(i)}\searrow a$. Which is in fact continuity on the right of the CDF.

Comment: I see you answered while I was typing mine.  Nevertheless there is some non-overlapping content in the answers so I will keep mine also.

Comment: @Michael no problem, it happens all the time.

Comment: Yep, totally agree. This is just how I proved it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This can be proven from the "continuity of probability" result for events that shrink to a limiting event: 
$$A_n\searrow A \implies P[A_n]\rightarrow P[A]$$ 
(and this is derived from the countable additivity axiom).

---

One reason this is important is that it helps students to be precise when they draw pictures of CDF functions.  They need to learn to be detail-oriented enough to respect this issue when points of discontinuity arise.

Another reason for importance is that it relates to this question:

**Question:** "What functions $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are valid CDF functions?"

**Answer:** A function $F(x)$ is a valid CDF, meaning that there exists a random variable $X$ for which $P[X\leq x] = F(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if and only if these four criteria are satisfied:

- $F(x)$ is nondecreasing.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} F(x) = 0$.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} F(x)=1$.
- $F(x)$ is right-continuous.

So the right-continuous property has a place of prominence in this fundamental question.

---

This fact is useful to resolve this natural question: Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be i.i.d. random variables uniform over $[-1,1]$.  Define 
$$ L_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
Does there exist a random variable $Y$ for which the distribution of $L_n$ converges to the distribution of $Y$?  The answer is "no" because: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[L_n\leq x] = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \mbox{ if $x >0$}\\
1/2 & \mbox{ if $x=0$}\\
0 & \mbox{ if $x<0$} 
\end{array}\right.$$
and, because this is not right-continuous, this is not a valid CDF function for any random variable.

Of course, the CDF of the always-zero random variable $0$ is the right-continuous unit step function, which differs from the above function only at the point of discontinuity at $x=0$.   Such issues are the reason why the definition of "$Y_n\rightarrow Y$ in distribution" has the caveat that the convergence $P[Y_n\leq y] \rightarrow P[Y\leq y]$ only needs to take place at points $y$ where $P[Y\leq y]$ is continuous. With this caveat in mind, it is correct to say that $L_n\rightarrow 0$ in distribution (and of course we also know $L_n\rightarrow 0$ with probability 1 by the law of large numbers).

Comment: I suppose this raises the natural question "which functions $h(x)$ can be pointwise limits of distributions $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[Y_n\leq y]$"?  In particular, is it possible to construct an example that replaces the "$1/2$ if $x=0$" in the above example with  "$1/3$ if $x=0$"?

Comment: I suppose the central limit theorem can help answer the question in the special case when $Y_n$ is constructed from i.i.d. random variables with finite mean and variance, in that case the $1/2$ is unavoidable.

Comment: I (think) the answer to the general $h(x)$ question above is "any $h(x)$ function that is nondecreasing and satisfies $0\leq h(x)\leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$."  Now if $Y_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ for $\{X_i\}$ iid with zero mean but infinite variance, I don't know if the $1/2$ is fundamental anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example!!

Comment: I asked a question about my $1/2$ question in the comment above, and it was answered, see here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221659/averaging-i-i-d-variables-equal-chance-to-be-right-and-left-of-the-mean

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't "have" to be. A distribution function is defined either as 
$$F_X(x)=\mathbb{P}_X((-\infty,x])=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$$

Then it is right continuous (follows from continuity of measures from above). It could be defined as
$$F_X(x)=\mathbb{P}_X((-\infty,x))=\mathbb{P}(X<x)=1-\mathbb{P}(X\geq x)$$
Then it is left continuous, which again follows from continuity of measures.