# Averaging i.i.d. variables: Equal chance to be right and left of the mean?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be i.i.d. random variables. Define 
$$ L_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, …\} $$
Using the central limit theorem, it can be shown that if $E[X_i]=0$ and $0<Var(X_i)<\infty$ then: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[L_n\leq x] =  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 &\mbox{ if $x > 0$} \\
c & \mbox{ if $x=0$}\\
0 & \mbox{ if $x<0$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
where $c=1/2$.  If the variance is infinite then the law of large numbers implies a similar structure for the cases $x>0$ and $x<0$, but the case $x=0$ is unclear to me.

**Questions:** For infinite variance, can we get different behavior for the case $x=0$, such as $c=1/3$?  Can we get related step-function structure when the mean does not exist, but with different behavior for the case $x=0$?

---

**Notes:**

- We can get such a limiting function with $c=1/3$ for random sequences with different structure, such as $L_n= A/n$ with $P[A=1]=2/3, P[A=-1]=1/3$.
- I came up with this question while reflecting on the question here: [Why does a C.D.F need to be right-continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221379/why-does-a-c-d-f-need-to-be-right-continuous/3221393#3221393)

Comment: I have added the clarification: "Can we get related [step-function] structure when the mean does not exist [but with different behavior for the case $x=0$]?" I originally intended this second part not so much as a "second question" but just to acknowledge that interesting examples when $L_n\rightarrow 0$ in distribution but with $c\neq 1/2$ might (for some reason) be easier to construct when the mean does not exist than when the mean exists but the variance is infinite. (Or, perhaps no such examples exist!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible for $c$ to take any value strictly between $0$ and $1$. The point is that there exist mean-zero stable distributions which are not symmetric about $0$ (of course, such a stable distribution cannot be Gaussian, and so it must have infinite variance). You may look at [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#/media/File:Levyskew_distributionPDF.png) to see how some of these stable distributions look.

Specifically, if $\alpha \in (1,2)$ and $\beta \in [-1,1]$, then it turns out that there exists a random variable $X$ whose characteristic function will look like $$\phi_X(t) = e^{-|t|^{\alpha}\big(1-i\beta \tan(\frac{\pi\alpha}{2})\text{sign}(t)\big).}$$ As it turns out, this distribution will have mean zero, and moreover (by varying $\alpha$ and $\beta$), $P(X<0)$ can be any predefined number $c\in(0,1)$. Furthermore, for iid copies one may check directly from the characteristic function that $n^{-1/\alpha}(X_1+...+X_n)$ has the same distribution as $X_1$. From this we can easily conclude that $$P(L_n<0) =P(n^{1-1/\alpha}L_n<0)= P(X<0)=c \in (0,1),$$ for all $n$, as desired. I do not know if $c=0$ or $c=1$ is a possible limit for nonzero random variables $X_i$, though it'd be interesting to find out.

Comment: Now, regarding the case of infinite mean, take $\alpha<1$ and one may obtain the same result, in fact in that case one has $P(L_n\le x) \to c$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to verify the easy things such as $n^{-1/\alpha}(X_1+...+X_n)$ has the same characteristic function as $X_1$, and the $P[L_n<0]$ calculation.  It is not obvious that such a characteristic function back-transforms to a valid PDF (i.e. nonnegative) or that $\beta$ controls $P[X<0]$ (though the linked pictures suggest that).  But this was a nicely written description of a deep theory that I was not familiar with.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Michael Those things are certainly not obvious at all. In fact, after closer inspection I am not even sure that $P(X<0)$ can take all values between $0$ and $1$: surely it is not true for a _fixed_ value of $\alpha \in (1,2)$ as I write in my answer (note that the picture has $\alpha=1/2$ which is inadmissible if we want a finite mean). However, I strongly believe that by making $\alpha$ closer and closer to $2$ and setting $\beta=1$ it is possible to make $c$ approach $1$ (and similarly by setting $\beta=-1$ we can make $c$ approach $0$). Numerically this is clear but a proof might take work

Comment: I see.  On your other comment: The $P[L_n\leq x]\rightarrow c$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is quite crazy!  If $c \in (0,1)$, given the Kolmogorov 0/1 law we have $P[L_n\rightarrow \infty]=P[L_n\rightarrow-\infty]=0$.  So it seems to me that we would need $L_n$ to take very large values for huge intervals of $n$, then "relatively quickly" change to taking very large-magnitude negative values for huge intervals of $n$, but infinitely oscillate in this way.

Comment: @Michael Yes this is true. If you search for (or simulate) pictures of $\alpha$-stable Levy processes for $\alpha<1$ then this is exactly the behavior you will see. In fact such processes have the property that for $c>0$, the distribution of $X_{c t}$ is the same as that of $c^{1/\alpha}X_t$. So the surprising thing is that (as opposed to the case of $\alpha>1$, e.g., Brownian motion) the spatial scaling as actually "bigger" than the temporal scaling. The Cauchy process ($\alpha=1$) is the case where the space and time scalings "equalize."

Comment: Also, in my second comment of this thread I of course meant "taking $\alpha$ closer and closer to $1$," rather than $2$.

Comment: I corrected the answer to be more precise. @sk

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer: if $X_i$'s are non-negative with infinite  mean than $L_n \to \infty$ a.s. an $P(L_n \leq x) \to 0$ for every $x$.

Comment: Haha.  Well yes, that is an easy side case (+1). There are certain situations where the mean does not exist but we still get convergence in distribution to 0, I was wondering if those cases can have weird things happening for $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[L_n\leq 0]$.  Or, is $1/2$ fundamental? Obviously we get $1/2$ whenever $X_i$ has a continuous distribution and has the same distribution as $-X_i$.