# Does the CMF of the degenerate distribution have to be right continuous?

Tags: probability-distributions

The CMF of the degenerate distribution at 0 is defined on Wikipedia as below:

$$
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \space \text{for} \space x<0 \\
1 & \space \text{for} \space x\ge 0
\end{cases}
$$

My question is, why do we define $F(0)=1$? Is it allowed define $F(0)=0$ and thus making $F$ left continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define it as $F(x)=\mathbb{P}(X<x)$ then it is automatically left continuous. We don't define it to be left or right continuous.

If you define it as $F(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$, then it is right continuous. This follows from continuity of measures.

See:
[Why does a C.D.F need to be right-continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221379/why-does-a-c-d-f-need-to-be-right-continuous/3221425#3221425)